# What will happen to AWS S3 bucket if I stop paying?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to put something important to S3 bucket and forget about it for some time.
The question is, if my credit card stops being active, and I forget to pay for some time, what will happen? Will they delete it or will they restrict access to it? (lets not take into account the notifications they might send to my email, for now; but I also wonder if some notifications will come.)

Thank you.

Comment: s3 is free for 12 months, and cheap after the free tier expires. I never have not paid, but going through google seems they give you a few chances until they delete your account.

Comment: @PHPBoob The [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) provides **5GB** of Amazon S3 storage for the first 12 months.

Answer (score 2):

Right from the horses mouth:

> **Important**: If you don't pay all past due charges and then reactivate
> your account within 60 days of suspension, resources on the account
> might be lost. If you don't pay all past due charges and reactivate
> your account within 90 days, then your account is terminated.
> Terminated accounts can't be reopened, and all resources on the
> account are lost.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/reactivate-suspended-account/